# Display same bean value in multiple JSP pages

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a jsp page where I have the login info entered by user. Internally, this values are fetched and compared to the bean value that I get from the database. Now once the user have logged in, I use the same bean value that I used to check the username and password to display the username of the person who have logged in. My question is how can I use the same username across multiple jsp pages i.e for all the jsp pages in my project without redundantly calling the method. Right now I am simply able to display the username in the main page that the user sees after loggin in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you just need to store the user bean in the HTTP session:

```
request.setSession().setAttribute("currentUser", theUser);
```

And in your JSP:

```
Hello <c:out value="${currentUser.name}"/>
```

and  to specifically target the session scoped attributes (in case of conflicts between scopes)

```
Hello <c:out value="${sessionScope.currentUser.name}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet. This is a old link. I am sorry I didnt close it. Thanks again.